# Fresh Windows 10 installation freezes on startup

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, freeze, hardware-failure

I have a desktop PC that was not used for around 4-5 months. I tried to boot it some days ago and it was freezing on startup (windows logo).

I tried to do a fresh windows installation the problem remained the same. After the installation on the first boot, it was freezing.
Then, I tried to install windows to an old HDD 5400rpm. This worked, the computer was not freezing.
This made me thought that the SSD (crucial MX100) was broken. I did a firmware update and a health status check the problem persisted.

So I bought a new Samsung 850 Evo. Fresh installation, the computer still freezes.
I tried to remove 1 ram module and switch them 1 by 1, nothing positive.
Sometimes it boots up until the Desktop, but it freezes within seconds.

I managed to enter safe mode, the computer was running fine.

Any ideas what might be broken? I guess its obviously a Hardware issue.

Comment: maybe PSU issue. do you have a 2nd PSU for testing purpose from a friend?

Comment: What makes you think that its PSU issue? The truth is that its pretty old, around 10 years old. I don't have one handy but I can probably get one to test.

Comment: old PSU can have Capacitor issues after several years. during boot, PCs require some power so maybe the PSu can't provide it.